403:Zoom Phone has not been enabled for this account
I'm trying to create a method to collect my account data using an API. I did all the necessary steps but I'm still getting "403 {"code":2031,"message":"Zoom Phone has not been enabled for this account.".
I have an activated server to server app, I gave phone:read permissions, I have Zoom Phone enabled in the user that crated the app and I have the Zoom phone enabled in my biilling account. Any ideas?
I got an access token and I used the https://zoom.us/oauth/token endpoint and then used the access token with the https://api.zoom.us/v2/phone/call_logs endpoint but without success.
